# PDO Count tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, count, pdo

The following function is designed to fetch the tables in the database.

```
$check = $fsdbh->query('show tables')->fetch();
```

It cannot be counted because it has an extra layer in it, the database name.

print_r():

```
Array ( [Tables_in_dbtest] => test [0] => test )
```

So We need to get one step further into the array and just count the number of databases. How would we do that.

Comment: The problem is not a nested/multi-dimensional array as you suggest. It is the fact you are getting both associative and numerical keys in your result array.  Please see Marwelln's answer below for good solution that will de-dupe your result array.

Comment: His method is only producing 1 table as I commented on not all of them.

Comment: That is probably because there is only one table in the currently selected database?

Answer (score 3):

The default fetch style is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, what you need is `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

See [the `fetch` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for more information.

This code should work for you:

```
$check = $fsdbh->query('show tables')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Another thing you could do is to change the default fetch style with [PDO::setAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` after you connect to your database.

```
$dbh = new PDO('...');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Either FETCH_NUM or FETCH_ASSOC should work in that it will prevent you from getting both associative and numerically indexed keys in your result (thus doubling the number of values in the array).

Comment: mmm. Works but it appears there is another problem. The 'show tables' is only getting one table, there are 2 on the server in this database

Comment: @RobinKnight, have your db user permission to access or read both tables?

Comment: @Marwelln Yes both are and any others I create are also excluded. The 'show tables' function is listing only the latest.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to do do

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='yourdbname';
```

Comment: That is not PDO. Can you turn it into a PDO query

Comment: A query is a query. PDO is simply one method for PHP to interface with a database. Regardless of which interface you use, it's all SQL under the hood.